# Как сохранить  ImageView изображение на телефон.

Tags: android, изображения

Вот собственно сам код. Он благопалучно позаимствован с хабра.

```
ImageView imageView; // ImageView, содержащий изображение, которое нужно сохранить String folderToSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(); // папка куда сохранять, в данном случае - корень SD-карты

private String SavePicture(ImageView iv, String folderToSave)
{

    OutputStream fOut = null;
    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();

    try {
        File file = new File(folderToSave, Integer.toString(time.year) + Integer.toString(time.month) + Integer.toString(time.monthDay) + Integer.toString(time.hour) + Integer.toString(time.minute) + Integer.toString(time.second) +".jpg"); // создать уникальное имя для файла основываясь на дате сохранения
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        Bitmap bitmap = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable().getBitmap();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // сохранять картинку в jpeg-формате с 85% сжатия.
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(),  file.getName()); // регистрация в фотоальбоме
    }
    catch (Exception e) // здесь необходим блок отслеживания реальных ошибок и исключений, общий Exception приведен в качестве примера
    {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Вопрос собственно в том что данная конструкция не работает, в чём может быть проблема? После нажатия на кнопку Save, ничего не происходит

```
public void btnSave_Click(View v){          SavePicture(imageView,folderToSave);     }
```

Может я что то не так делаю ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У тебя где-то вылетает эксепшн, о необходимости честной ловли которого автор кода заботливо написал в комментарии. Попробуй так:

```
public void btnSave_Click(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(SavePicture(imageView, folderToSave)).show();
}
```

И посмотри что за сообщение покажет после клика.
Скорее всего, это будет IOEcxeption.

Comment: /mnt/sdcard/2012821113722.jpg :open failed:EACCES(Permission denied)

вот такое вылазит

Comment: а <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> в манифесте есть?

Comment: М. Кстати. Если эмулятор - проверь что под sd-card место выделено.

Comment: добавил в манифест <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  Всё заработало, большое спасибо за подсказку, сохраняется в корень sd карты.